# Resorting data from a multidimensional list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a dataset that is generated in a 4D table. A snippet would look something like:

{{{{x,y},{x2,y2},...}...}...} and so on, in code form:

```
data=Table[{RandomReal[{0, 4}], RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {InTh, 5}, {InE, 6}, backEn, 780}, {backAngle, 0, 89}]
```

Now, I want to sort/rebin the data in such a way that a program goes over the list and sums y values which lie in a certain x range, let's say my bins are generated by using:

```
driftBins=Table[i,{i,0,4,0.001}]
```

The approach I currently have is really poor and uses For loops as I am not really familiar with Mathematica to an expert level.

```
driftRebinned2 = {};
start = AbsoluteTime[];
For[i = 1, i < Length[driftBins], i++,
  summy = 0;
  For[InTh = 1, InTh <= 5, InTh++,
   For[InE = 1, InE < 6, InE++,
    For[backEn = 1, backEn <= 780, backEn++,
     For[backAngle = 1, 
      backAngle <= 90, backAngle++,
      If[driftBins[[i + 1]] > 
         data[[InTh, InE, backEn, backAngle]][[1]] && 
        driftBins[[i]] <= data[[InTh, InE, backEn, backAngle]][[1]], 
       summy = summy + data[[InTh, InE, backEn, backAngle]][[2]]]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]; AppendTo[
   driftRebinned2, {(driftBins[[i]] + driftBins[[i + 1]])/2, summy}];
  ];
AbsoluteTime[] - start
```

Is there a way to optimize this code or do it in a table? I tried doing it via a table but the issue I encounter there is I am not sure how to sum up y values that lie within a certain x range.

The data generation is just an example. My real data is a result of reading a data file where the values of the data file are weighted by a combination of weighing function which depend on the four iterators.

Comment: You could try using `Compile` along with ``Internal`Bag``. But there is certainly also a high-level approach using tensor routines.

Comment: What is `driftBins`? It is currently undefined.

Comment: Sorry edited it. Yhe driftTable was supposed to be driftBins. Also the data generation is just an example. My real data comes from data files weighted with respect to a weighing factor dependent on the iterator i.e. inTh, inE, backen, backangle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume here that the bins are equally spaced.

Starting like @HenrikSchumacher suggests:

```
data = Join[RandomReal[{0, 4}, {5, 6, 780, 90, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 6, 780, 90, 1}], 5];
data1 = Flatten[data, 3];
```

If your data need to be weighted depending on their four indices, you could instead first do something like

```
weighteddata = MapIndexed[{#1[[1]], f[#1[[2]],#2]}&, data, {4}];
```

with `f` some function you define that does the weighting. Then use `data1 = Flatten[weighteddata, 3]` instead.

For each data point, round the $x$-coordinate down to the nearest thousandth (you may use `Round` or `Ceiling` instead of `Floor` to define the bins, depending on what exactly you need):

```
data2 = {Floor[#[[1]], 0.001], #[[2]]} & /@ data1;
```

Gather together all data points with the same $x$-coordinate (rounded down to the nearest thousandth):

```
A = GatherBy[data2, First];
```

From these gathered lists, calculate for each bin (i) the $x$-value of the lower bin edge (or the center of the bin, or whatever) and (ii) the sum of the $y$-values (or the mean, or length, or whatever):

```
B = (#[[1, 1]] -> Total[#[[All, 2]]]) & /@ A;
```

The results in `B` are in random order.
Make an ordered list of all bins and their sum:

```
bins = Range[0, 4, 0.001];
Transpose[{bins, Lookup[B, bins, 0]}]
```

> {{0, ...}, {0.001, ...}, {0.002, ...}, ..., {4, ...}}

(The dots stand for the sum values in each bin.)

If you prefer having the bin centers as first coordinate instead of the bin lower limits, then you could do

```
bins = Range[0, 3.999, 0.001];
Transpose[{bins+0.0005, Lookup[B, bins, 0]}]
```

> {{0.0005, ...}, {0.0015, ...}, {0.0025, ...}, ..., {3.9995, ...}}

I agree with @HenrikSchumacher that `BinLists` is nicer than my use of `GatherBy` here.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and working. The whole thing works like a charm and in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't checked this for correctness, but in runs in about a second:

```
data = Join[
   RandomReal[{0, 4}, {5, 6, 780, 90, 1}],
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 6, 780, 90, 1}],
   5
   ];
```

Because the nested structure of `data` is not need anywhere, I flatten it to a matrix. Afterwards I employ `Nearest` to find the correct bin for each entry of `data1` (exploting that the bins are equally spaced). Afterwards, a compiled routine `assemble` adds the contributions for each bin into a large vector.

```
data1 = Flatten[data, 3];

driftBins = Table[i, {i, 0., 4., 0.001}];
bincenters = MovingAverage[driftBins, 2];
binradii = 0.5 (driftBins[[2]] - driftBins[[1]]);
idx = Developer`ToPackedArray[
  Nearest[bincenters -> Automatic, data1[[All, 1]], {1, binradii}]
  ];


assemble = 
 Compile[{{idx, _Integer, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}, {n, _Integer}},
  Block[{a},
   a = Table[0., {n}];
   Do[a[[idx[[i]]]] += y[[i]], {i, 1, Length[idx]}];
   a
   ]
  ];

symmylist = assemble[Flatten[idx], data1[[All, 2]], Length[bincenters]];
driftRebinned2 = Transpose[{bincenters, symmylist}];
```

A somewhat more flexible approach is by using `BinLists`:

```
sum = Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}},
   Total[a[[All, 2]]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

symmylist3 = sum[
   Flatten[
    BinLists[Flatten[data, 3];, {driftBins}, {{-∞, ∞}}], 
    1
    ]
   ];
driftRebinned3 = Transpose[{bincenters, symmylist3}];
```

Comment: Hi, your solution also works like a charm. Thank you so much however unfortunately I can only choose one correct answer, sorry :(

Comment: No worries. You're welcome.